# How to open database encrypted with sqlcipher

Tags: sqlite.swift

Could anyone post code sample of how to open sqlcipher database? I guess that we need to call the key function in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've installed SQLite.swift with SQLCipher support (if not, [follow these instructions](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#using-sqliteswift-with-sqlcipher)), you merely need to call the `key` function on your `Database` object:

```
import SQLite

let db = Database("path/to/ciphered.sqlite3")
db.key("your_key")
```

Once keyed, you can change the encryption key using `rekey`:

```
db.rekey("your_new_key")
```

Comment: The instructions are to include SQLCipher on your Podfile: `pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher'`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift).

- To see how to call the underlying sqlcipher functions. e.g.
  `sqlite3_key()`, see [Cipher.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/SQLiteCipher/Cipher.swift)
- To see how to open a sqlcipher database in SQlite.swift with a key:
  [CipherTests.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/SQLiteCipher%20Tests/CipherTests.swift)